# Google search mostra parent directory em vez do titulo e descrição

Tags: html, html-meta-tag

Boa Tarde, reparei que o google tem como titulo á minha página web parent directory e como descrição lista os ficheiros e pastas, quando no ficheiro html tenho o  e os meta dados correctos.

Alguém me sabe dizer o porquê?

Obrigado

Comment: Qual é o seu site?

Comment: Verifique se tem as meta tags "title" e "description" contento esses valores que disse.

Comment: www.urbanact.pt as meta tags tem valores diferents a estes que o google apresenta

Comment: Caso muito estranho, aparentemente seu site está  com as meta tags corretas. Tentou utilizar o Google Webmastertools? 
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home
Ele pode te dar mais informações

Comment: era uma questão de tempo, já está tudo direito agora, pelo que percebi o google demora a fazer as alterações dos metadados. Obrigado